# Как найти функции round в mvs 2010?

Tags: c++, функции

Обшарил заголовки math.h и cmath в visual studio 2010 и не нашел. Не знаю, как выкручиваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как выкручиваться.

```
floor(x+0.5)
```

Например, при x=1.4 результат будет равен 1.0, а при x=1.5 будет 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Видимо плохо искали.

```
#include "math.h"

...

int i = round(10.6); // 11
```

Вполне работает. В файле math.h на 1125 строке:

```
inline float __CRTDECL round(_In_ float _X) throw()
    {return (roundf(_X)); }
```

**Обновление**

Впрочем [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170385/c-math-functions) говорят, что в виндовых библиотеках round в math.h действительно нет. Вероятно, со временем все же добавили, поскольку меня VS 2013 и там все есть

**Обновление 1**

> я так подозреваю что удаление и изменение стандартов создано в этой версии с учетом того чтоб люди переходили на платную версию

Сильно сомневаюсь.

**Обновление 2**

> а если нет то что им стоит выдать бесплатно допилиную версию тем более для студентов

Во-первых, именно для студентов они выдают полнофункциональные версии своих продуктов по программе DreamSpark совершенно бесплатно

во-вторых я говорил о том, что ваша версия о том, что они якобы урезают стандарт  языка в бесплатных версиях - это чепуха. Так никто не делает. В бесплатных версиях урезают функционал самой IDE, а не языка.

Для MS продукты типа VS по сути даже не являются способом заработка Они получают с них весьма небольшой процент своих доходов

Comment: http://shot.qip.ru/00zS9s-6EBATVbrn/ нет ее, а функция floor есть. у меня бесплатная экспресс версия для студентов. заголовки подключены

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что удаление и изменение стандартов создано в этой версии с учетом того, чтоб люди переходили на платную версию. Как мне кажется, ибо урезано очень много.

Comment: А если нет, то что им стоит выдать бесплатно допилиную версию, тем более для студентов. Я б не сказал, что в майкрософт работают такие чайники, которые пропускают такие простые ошибки. Это ж один из их брендов.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы.